# Is there a need to recreate a new stream by gprc stream client side?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, http2, grpc-go

There is a gRPC stream server and client. the client dials to server through gRPC bidirectional stream. The server is running on a kunbeness docker.

After upgrading kubeness server once, the client always gets an EOF error when trying to send a request to stream server. I found that the TCP connection is alive. Why?

Do I need to recreate a new strean by calling "NewStream" API in go-grpc?

```
func (cc *ClientConn) NewStream(ctx context.Context, desc *StreamDesc, method string, opts ...CallOption) (ClientStream, error)
```

If I set keep-alive parameters when dialing to gRPC stream server, does the stream would be reconnected automatically or just the TCP connection?

Answer (score 0):

> If I set keep-alive parameters when dialing to gRPC stream server,
>   does the stream would be reconnected automatically or just the TCP
>   connection?

Just the TCP connection.

Restarting after an io.EOF is not uncommon practice, so your client-side will need to restart the stream.

Your retry loop may want to add wait/sleep backoff between retries & max retry attempts to guard against a runaway busy loop.

Comment: So it's the application's responsibility to take care of the connection alive.